# Android Studio Gradle Sync Failure

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.2

I've been trying to run just a simple app with some in-built views, but on startup of Android Studio, Gradle sync completes with few errors. I've tried multiple methods I saw on the Internet, but nothing works. I also replaced the gradle-2.14.1 folder from Android Studio files, by downloading the zip file and extracting, but that doesn't work too.

Here is the code for build.gradle(Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Code for build.gradle(app):

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.heenamehta.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree( dir: 'libs' , include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Gradle-wrapper-properties:

```
#Mon Dec 28 10:00:20 PST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

I have also attached the image showing errors in Messages section. [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o2ZQ.png)
Also for the extra info, I am using:
 Android Studio 2.2.3  with 
 SDK API level 23 and
Build tools 25.0.2

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle` [app-level] import all of those libraries, which are listed in error list and also update your android studio-

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree( dir: 'libs' , include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

        //Here - add all of those libraries dependencies
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```